# How can I fit a list of dictionaries in form of strings to actual list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, lambda, string-formatting

So I am working on a dataset and I have a column that consists of country ids and country names in dict format. But when I try to evaluate the dictionary, I see that it is actually a string.

When I print a column it seems like this:

```
df["production_countries"][0]
```

> [{"iso_3166_1": "US", "name": "United States of America"},
> {"iso_3166_1": "GB", "name": "United Kingdom"}]

When I try to add a new column from this dictionaries, I see that it is a string inside the list.
So how can I evaluate this seemingly list of dicts to make actual list of dicts?

I wanted to add a column that give 1 or 0 if the US values exists in that column.

```
df["US_count"] = df["production_countries"].apply(lambda x:\
[[int(d["name"] == "United States") for d in dicts]  for dicts in x])
```